# htaccess rewrite still some problems, getting a bit complex eek!

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, url-rewriting

Another edition to my .htaccess rewriting saga. Everything is now working to a degree but still have some issues.

I have numerous rules to move old urls to new urls, passing variables etc - however there are still a couple of things i need to add, and for the life of me cannot figure out.

I have 3 urls that are directing/rewriting as below.

---

1 www.mydomain.com/news/dentistry_dental/index.php

2 www.mydomain.com/news/dentistry_dental/index.php?month=April&year=2011

3 www.mydomain.com/news/dentistry_dental/article_detail.php?article=1234&title=some-title

---

These are redirected & rewritten perfectly to the new urls respectively

---

1 www.mydomain.com/dental_news/

2 www.mydomain.com/dental_news/April-2011

3 www.mydomain.com/dental_news/1234-some-title

---

**However... Here is the problem #1 The following urls are also redirecting as below**

---

4 www.mydomain.com/news/it_technology/index.php?month=April&year=2011

5 www.mydomain.com/news/it_technology/article_detail.php?article=1234&title=some-title

---

Which are also directing to the same urls as the dental redirects

---

4 www.mydomain.com/dental_news/April-2011

5 www.mydomain.com/dental_news/1234-some-title

---

Which shouldnt be happening. The it_technology news articles have now been removed so i wish to redirect them either to my homepage with a 410 or something similar, whichever is the best option really.

My current .htaccess looks as follows.

Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on

```
rewritecond %{http_host} ^mydomain.com [nc]
rewriterule ^(.*)$ http://www.mydomain.com/$1 [r=301,nc]

    # Rewrite all index.php to root: / ( with perm redirect )
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/generator/
    RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^.*/index.php
    RewriteRule ^(.*)index.php$ http://www.mydomain.com/$1 [R=301]

    RewriteRule ^products/dental-digital-imaging/([^/]*)_([^/]*)$ /products/digital_xray.php?id=$1&product=$2 [L]
    RewriteRule ^products/package_deals.php$ http://www.mydomain.com/products/dental-computer-network-bundles [R=301]
    RewriteRule ^products/computer_hardware.php$ http://www.mydomain.com/products/dental-computer-solutions [R=301]
    RewriteRule ^products/individual_computers.php$ http://www.mydomain.com/products/dental-computer-systems [R=301]
    RewriteRule ^products/digital_xray_imaging.php$ http://www.mydomain.com/products/dental-digital-imaging [R=301]

    RewriteRule dental_news/$ /news/dentistry_dental/?rewrite [L]

    # Rewrite dental news article to neat nice url
    # Protect from looping because of previous rules
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !rewrite
    RewriteRule ^dental_news/([0-9]*)-([^/]*)$ news/dentistry_dental/article_detail.php?article=$1&title=$2&rewrite [L]

    #Conditional rewrite of old news article path to new one with 301 redirect
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/dental_news/
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} article=([0-9]*)&title=([^&]*)$
    RewriteRule (.*) /dental_news/%1-%2? [L,R=301]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/dental_news/
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} month=([^&]*)&year=([^&]*)$
    RewriteRule (.*) /dental_news/%1-%2? [R=301]

    # Protect from looping because of previous rules
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !rewrite
    RewriteRule news/dentistry_dental/$ /dental_news/ [R=301]

    # Protect from looping because of previous rules
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !rewrite
    RewriteRule ^dental_news/([a-zA-Z]*)-([0-9]*)/?$ news/dentistry_dental/index.php?month=$1&year=$2&rewrite [L]

    # Rewrite URL stripping .php Extension
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

My only other requirement would be to add a trailing slash to the php files served ( that have allready add the .php extension removed with the last rule in my .htaccess.

I have tried numerous ways that i have found via google, but all of them cuase probelms with my other rules.

Hopefully someone can help me finish this off once and for all.

Regards
M

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure is getting complicated :)  Try changing these lines (I think there are 2):

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/dental_news/
```

to:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/news/dentistry_dental/
```

That way its only going to redirect the old dental news URLs to there respective new ones.

Comment: Hi clmarquart, thanks again for your input, i shall try this option also and report back shortly, many thanks again for your help.

Regards M

Comment: Worked perfectly - i have redirected my old it news pages also, so thats all sorted, only the trailing slashes to sort now :)

Answer (score 0):

Trivially, your problem is the catch-all rules:

```
#Conditional rewrite of old news article path to new one with 301 redirect
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/dental_news/
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} article=([0-9]*)&title=([^&]*)$
RewriteRule (.*) /dental_news/%1-%2? [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/dental_news/
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} month=([^&]*)&year=([^&]*)$
RewriteRule (.*) /dental_news/%1-%2? [R=301]
```

Restrict them to the path you want to rewrite, i.e. replace `.*` with something more specific, like:

```
#Conditional rewrite of old news article path to new one with 301 redirect
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/dental_news/
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} article=([0-9]*)&title=([^&]*)$
RewriteRule ^news/dentistry_dental/index.php$ /dental_news/%1-%2? [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/dental_news/
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} month=([^&]*)&year=([^&]*)$
RewriteRule ^news/dentistry_dental/index.php$ /dental_news/%1-%2? [R=301]
```

You can do the `news/it_technology` redirect as a standard redirect.

```
RewriteRule ^news/it_technology http://www.thepage.com/ [R=301,L]
```

It might technically be more correct to do a 410, but the 410 code is really optional. You might also want to make it 404, and then have a link from the 404 page to the main page.

Comment: Ahhh, thank you very much, i will try what you have suggested and report back shortly. Many thanks for your time.

Regards M

Comment: The changing of the existing rules worked, however the 2nd rewrite for the it_Techonolgy didnt, i have sorted this now and used the solution below. Just need to sort my trailing slashes now. :)